# Access variable in callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I am trying trying to alert a node variable in my copyfile callback function but I'm getting an error. What is missing?

```
function myFunc(){
    var node = "my node";
    CopyFile("test","test1",function (){
        alert(node); //error here VM29198:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: node is not defined(…)
    }, function (sender, args) {

    }); 
}

function CopyFile(param1, param2, callbackSuccess, callbackFail){
    callAnotherfunction(function(){
        callbackSuccess();
    },function(){
        callbackFail();
    });
}
```

Comment: What is problem? See https://jsfiddle.net/jvpockz1/